# Java: .print not working the way I intended in my code

Tags: java

So this is my very first homework assignment regarding code and I've spent the past few hours trying to figure this out but I'm completely stumped.

I'm trying to find the area of a triangle by inputting its three sides (Which I managed to figure out how to do), but when I actually compile and run the code, my .print isn't working as intended.

Here's my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Purpose: To get the area of a triangle

public class ComputeTriangleArea  {

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creating a scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //  Entering dimensions
        double x1 = scanner.nextDouble(); double y1 = scanner.nextDouble(); 
        double x2 = scanner.nextDouble(); double y2 = scanner.nextDouble(); 
        double x3 = scanner.nextDouble(); double y3 = scanner.nextDouble();

        // Inputting side 1
        System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 1: ");
        double side1 = Math.sqrt((x1-x2) * (x1-x2) + (y1-y2) * (y1-y2));

        // Inputting side 2
        System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 2: ");
        double side2 = Math.sqrt((x1-x3) * (x1-x3) + (y2-y3) * (y2-y3));

        // Inputting side 3
        System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 3: ");
        double side3 = Math.sqrt((x2-x3) * (x2-x3) + (y2-y3) * (y2-y3));

        // Convert to Area
        double s = (side1+side2+side3) / 2;
        double area = Math.sqrt(s * (s-side1) * (s-side2) * (s-side3));

        // Display the result
        System.out.printf("The area is %.2f\n", area);
    }
}
```

and the result is if I input let's say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

it shows up as:

java -cp . ComputeTriangleArea

1

2

3

4

5

6

Enter the dimensions of side 1: Enter the dimensions of side 2: Enter the dimensions of side 3: The area is 3.87

Exit code: 0

Would anyone mind guiding me in the right direction?

Thank you so so much!

Edit: Here's the code I managed to get from the help of everyone in the comments below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Purpose: To get the area of a triangle

public class ComputeTriangleArea  {

// main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Creating a scanner
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// Inputting side 1
scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 1: ");
double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
double y1 = scanner.nextDouble();

// Inputting side 2
System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 2: ");
double x2 = scanner.nextDouble();
double y2 = scanner.nextDouble();

// Inputting side 3
System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 3: ");
double x3 = scanner.nextDouble();
double y3 = scanner.nextDouble();

double side1 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
double side2 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x3) * (x1 - x3) + (y1 - y3) * (y1 - y3));
double side3 = Math.sqrt((x2 - x3) * (x2 - x3) + (y2 - y3) * (y2 - y3));

// Convert to Area
double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
double area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));

// Display the result
System.out.printf("The area is %.2f\n", area);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the intended behavior?

Comment: I'd like for it to be something like

"Enter the dimensions of side 1: (I then enter the two dimensions of Side 1)".

If that makes sense! Let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: You never ask for input after you print out "Enter dimensions of side 1". Are the dimensions supposed to be resolved to `x1`, `x2`, etc?

Comment: Exactly! So the dimensions of side 1 should be the four inputs of x1, x2, y1, y2 which is shown in the formula "double side1 = Math.sqrt((x1-x2) * (x1-x2) + (y1-y2) * (y1-y2));"

Comment: So move the lines `double x1 = in.nextDouble();` to just after you print "Enter side one"

Comment: If I try that out, I get the error "ComputeTriangleArea.java:26: error: cannot find symbol"

Comment: Did you put it after you calculate `side1`? (It needs to be above that, but below the print statement)

Comment: Yup! I put it above side 1 but below the print!

Comment: And you still got the error? Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Going off your advice and some of the rest I've seen in the comments and following off of what Gavin gave me I managed to figure out what to do which I'll edit into the OP! Thank you so so much for your help!

This in particular helped me figure out where I was going wrong again so thank you again!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, so please do not edit in the answer into the question. Instead you have the option to accept the answer the helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
// main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creating a scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Inputting side 1
    System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 1: ");
    double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    double y1 = scanner.nextDouble();

    // Inputting side 2
    System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 2: ");
    double x2 = scanner.nextDouble();
    double y2 = scanner.nextDouble();

    // Inputting side 3
    System.out.print("Enter the dimensions of side 3: ");
    double x3 = scanner.nextDouble();
    double y3 = scanner.nextDouble();

    double side1 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    double side2 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x3) * (x1 - x3) + (y2 - y3) * (y2 - y3));
    double side3 = Math.sqrt((x2 - x3) * (x2 - x3) + (y2 - y3) * (y2 - y3));

    // Convert to Area
    double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
    double area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));

    // Display the result
    System.out.printf("The area is %.2f\n", area);
}
```

**Updated**
Use single `Scanner` instead of multiple create `Scanner`, the `enter` key would not break `System.in`(Which i'm incorrect previously with thought `enter` key would break `System.in`)

Comment: That worked! Would you mind explaining to be what you did to fix my code?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @MrOutside, apart from using 3 `Scanner` objects, this solution works. So, have only 1 `Scanner` and use the rest of this solution.

Comment: Creating multiple Scanner objects using System.in, is not only a wrong, it's dangerous, and leads to brittle programs that may break easily. Please please do not recommend this. Also, please avoid answers that are code dumps as the explanation is more important than the code since the answer needs to be helpful to future visitors, not just the OP.

Comment: Yes, `enter` would not close the `System.in`. So no need create Scanner multiple times. I just updated the answer. Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels, @GBlodgett comments

Comment: Please add textual explanation to your answer. Posting a code dump answer helps only the OP if that.

Comment: I do mostly understand where I went wrong now!

The only part that I'm confused with, which I can ask my professor if I can't figure it out from the comments is why adding ONLY
    double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    double y1 = scanner.nextDouble();
Beneath my Side 1 works instead of requiring x2 and y2 as well.

Comment: @gavincook: please [edit] your answer and explain the answer that you propose (as has been requested several times). State what the original poster is doing wrong, and why the changes that you propose should work.

Comment: i just explained what may cause misunderstand below the answer, Thanks guys' remind.

Answer (score 0):

That output is expected from the code you wrote.
I assume you want the output to be (please provide expected output)

```
Enter the dimensions of side 1: 1 2
Enter the dimensions of side 2: 3 4
Enter the dimensions of side 3: 5 6
The area is 3.87
```

If you observe your code, you've scanned all the 6 numbers first and are then printing the statements. Thus the output is as you've got.

If you want the output to appear as I've shown, then you need to print statement for each side, scan 2 numbers after each print statement.

Comment: Exactly! That's the intended output I'd like. Thank you for putting it in words for me.